# Why does the C++ ICU Calendar::getTime(...) return a double?

Tags: c++, icu

`icu::Calendar::getTime(...)` returns a `UDate` which is a `double` typedef.

However, creating a Calendar and setting its milliseconds to a positive value, still yields a `::getTime(...)` result with 0 in a decimal place.

Why not just return a long instead?